# Use multiple values in iteratee shorthad for lodash predicate

Tags: typescript, lodash

In the [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) there is the following example:

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

_.filter(users, ['age', 36]);
// => objects for ['barney']
```

Is it possible to use a shorthand method to get the same result as the following function:

```js
_.filter(users, ({ age }) => age === 36 || 40));
// => objects for ['barney', 'fred']
```

I was thinking in the line of ([Code Sandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-blackburn-fei7hg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) with the examples):

```js
import * as _ from "lodash";

var users = [
  { user: "barney", age: 36, active: true },
  { user: "fred", age: 40, active: false }
];

// does not work
const result1 = _.filter(users, ["age", 36 || 40]);
console.info("result1: ", result1);
// => objects for ['barney']

// does not work
const result2 = _.filter(users, ["age", [36, 40]]);
console.info("result2: ", result2);
// => []
```

Comment: there's no such shorthand provided by the `lodash` according to the docs

Comment: btw you might be using the incorrect expression: `age === 36 || 40` is `true` in all the cases, fe when `age` is `42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. As you can see from the documentation **predicates that are not equalities are handled with functions**. I think the best compromise to obtain a valid result with a similar syntax is:

```js
const result1 = _.filter(users, (user)=> [36,40].includes(user["age"]));
console.info("result1: ", result1);
```

Notice that if you are using typescript you might have to add `[key: string]: any` or something similar according to your object structure

Otherwise, you have to create a function and do something like:

```js
const containsValueForKey = (user, key, values) => {
  return values.includes(user[key])
}

const result1 = _.filter(users, (user)=> containsValueForKey(user, "age", [36,40]));
console.info("result1: ", result1);
```